# Expanding Worksheet_Change to Numerous Range Values

Tags: excel, vba

I was hoping someone could help me with a worksheet_change code that I would like to expand to numerous areas.  Every attempt I make I keep getting a end if code error.

Currently the code reads as:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("b6,b33,b60,b87,b113,b140")) Is Nothing Then
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Offset(-3, 0) = Now
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error GoTo 0
End If

If Target.Address = Range("D6").Address Then
    If Target = "Agent" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("B6:C6").Copy Range("B11:C11")
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End If

End Sub
```

What I would also like included would apply the second work_sheet change item to other areas on the same sheet. So if I was rewriting that portion it would read:

```
If Target.Address = Range("D33").Address Then
    If Target = "Agent" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("B33:C33").Copy Range("B38:C38")
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

If Target.Address = Range("D60").Address Then
    If Target = "Agent" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("B60:C60").Copy Range("B65:C65")
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

If Target.Address = Range("D87").Address Then
    If Target = "Agent" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("B87:C87").Copy Range("B92:C92")
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

If Target.Address = Range("D113").Address Then
    If Target = "Agent" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("B113:C113").Copy Range("B118:C118")
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

If Target.Address = Range("D140").Address Then
    If Target = "Agent" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("B140:C140").Copy Range("B145:C145")
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
```

Any help in how to get to actually work would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go this way:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, range("b6,b33,b60,b87,b113,b140")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Offset(-3, 0) = Now
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        On Error GoTo 0
    Else
        If Target.Value2 = "Agent" Then
            If Not Intersect(Target, range("D6,D33,D60,D87,D113,D140")) Is Nothing Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                Target.Offset(, -2).Resize(, 2).Copy Target.Offset(5,-2)
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! The code seems to work however it is building the information in cells D and E for the respective range. Do you know how to manipulate the code so it builds the info in cells B and C? I tried altering the target off set but it doesn't want to work for me.

Comment: see edited answer `Target.Offset(, -2).Resize(, 2).Copy Target.Offset(5,-2)`